# Moving part of git repo into new repo with reference to the old one

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a repository which contains both my main project and an optional module which should really be in a repo of its own.  What I'd like to do is move this module into its own repo, ideally preserving its history, and have a reference back to the main repository so the latest code can still be pulled into it.

To illustrate, my repo looks like something this

```
Main repo
├── Core code
├── Mandatory module
├── Optional module dependencies
└── Optional module core
```

And I'd like it to look like this

```
Main repo
├── Core code
└── Mandatory module

New repo
├── Optional module dependencies
├── Optional module core
└── <reference to Main repo>
```

I've managed to gather that git subtree seems to be the way to go, but the guides and examples I've found instruct how to move a project out into a new repo, and have a reference to it still exist in the main one, which isn't quite what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to split the repo and make the 'optional' module a submodule of the main repo?  It would be more the standard "git way" and would be easiest for users of the main repo to use.

Comment: The optional module has its own team working on it and we want to completely seperate them from the main repository, theb include their latest compiled DLL into our project when we make a build.  People working in the Main repository do not need anything from inside the optional module, but those who are working on the Optional module need to be given read-only access to the main repo.

I'm still relatively new to git, so happy to admit I may be going down the wrong path with this.

Comment: If the only consumers of the repositories are internal development, the simplest way would be to keep the repositories completely separate.  Their 'reference to main repo' would just be another clone beside their repo.  They'd compile their dll and just copy or symlink it into the main repo directory.  If it's an open source project where the end-user may need all the source files, a submodule in the main repo would be in order.